# Pronunciation of 개 versus 게

Tags: pronunciation, difference

Is there a difference between the pronunciation of 개 (dog) versus 게 (crab)?  Or do you just have to use context to know which one is being spoken about?

Comment: 야, 게 먹으러 갈까? (Hey, why don't we go grab some "crabs?") / 뭐? 개를 먹자고? (What? Did you just say "dogs?") / 아니, 게 말야. 아이 말고 어이. (No, I mean crabs; Eo-i one, not A-i.)

Comment: There's a very very small difference in pronunciation between 개 and 게. But you just have to use context.

Comment: ㅔ sounds [e] and ㅐ sounds [ae]. However, phonetic values of those two vowels are getting less distinguishable in these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory (the "Standard" Korean language), there's a difference.  In practice, there isn't.

On the other hand, if there's no context (e.g., "개/게 먹으러 갈까?", where both interpretation would make sense), since people "know" that they should sound different, they may exaggerate the difference to disambiguate. Then the vowel in 개 would move closer to ㅏ (somewhat similar to American English "cat"), and the vowel in 게 would move closer to ㅣ with more flattened lips.

Or they could just "spell it out": "아이" (ㅐ) or "어이" (ㅔ).

So if you can't hear the difference in a casual conversation, don't worry: it's perfectly normal.

Comment: There's definitely a difference in pronunciation of '개'  vs '게'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 개 is pronounced by wider opened mouth than 게 is.